# convert CheckBoxFor to jQuery UI button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have some check boxes in an MVC app, I'd like to convert to the fancy JQuery UI buttons as detailed here: https://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox

My code:

```
<td align="center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.rJanVal)</td>
```

Sample code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check"><label for="check">Toggle</label>
```

How do I do it? I don't understand enough about what happens in here "(model => model.rJanVal)", so that I can convert the code. New to C# and MVC which is why I struggle.

Please help :)

Comment: Check box value will be true or false? please show your controller side code

Answer (score 0):

`(model => model.rJanVal)` will result in the generation of the attributes `name` and `id` relatively to the property you gave (only for the HTML helpers generating inputs, selects, textareas, ...).

For `labels`, it will generate the attribute `for`.

So your checkbox should have `name="rJanVal"` and `id="rJanVal"`.

And the `label` will have `for="rJanVal"`.

So, you can write your `CSHTML` code like this:

```
<td align="center">
    <div id="buttons>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.rJanVal)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.rJanVal)
    </div>
</td>
```

And the `JS`:

```
$(function() {
    $("#rJanVal").button();
    $("#buttons").buttonset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you convert it? Just add a class to the razor checkbox like so:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.rJanVal, new { @class = "jqueryChkbox" })
```

and then just call the jquery function over it.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".jqueryChkbox").button();
});
</script>
```

If you want a button group:

```
<div id="jqueryChkboxGroup">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.foo)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.bar)

<div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#jqueryChkboxGroup").buttonset();
});
</script>
```